# jquery plugin mask literal

Tags: jquery, plugins, mask

I have a phone field text box. I want (925) xxx-xxxx where "(925)" is the default area code unless user change it.

I tried `$("#phone").mask("(925) 999-999");` but it doesn't work because 9 is a place holder instead of a literal. It does not accept ("\925") which I would think it's an escape. Is there a way to preset the values with 9 in it?

Comment: You'll have to set the value after setting the mask... What mask plugin, specifically, are you using?

Comment: I was using jQuery mask plugin: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

But I am willing to use any plugin to work it out. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value using

```
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-999").val('925');
```

However, it does not show the mask until the user start typing. I could not find a way in the plugin methods to trigger the mask.

The best I could do was using a placeholder, and setting the value on focus:

```
$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999', {  
    placeholder: '(925) '
}).on('focus', function() { 
    if(!this.value) 
        $(this).val('(925) '); 
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, could you show me in the JSFiddle please?